# How to configure ekf_localization_node in robot_localization package

Tags: navigation, robot-localization, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to use ekf node in robot_localization package, I have odom and Imu data [check discussion](http://answers.ros.org/question/200952/computing-robot_position-of-robot-using-robot_localization/?answer=201024#post-id-201024).

Is it possible to calculate robot_Pose with out using `tf` and `urdf` ?

should I start all node together in launch file??

correct me If i am wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201029/how-to-configure-ekf_localization_node-in-robot_localization-package/) by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2015-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-01-19**:
How to compare  this position with ground truth.

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-01-19**:
@Tom Moore and @Anas alhashimi plz look into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on the frames in which your data is reported. If your odometry or IMU data is in a frame other than your *world_frame* or *base_link_frame*, then you will need to provide a transform using `tf` so that `robot_localization` knows how to transform the data. I would advise that you start `robot_localization` in its own launch file. How you organize your launch files for everything else is entirely up to you. `robot_localization` doesn't need any URDF models, unless you are using those models to provide the `tf` transforms for your sensors.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-01-21**:
It is working Now, Is there any way to draw a graph or plot for robot_localization's output. (Odometry/filtering)? Some default Covariance matrix is given, on which basis I should update that one.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-01-21**:
Have you tried [rviz](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz)?

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-01-21**:
Nope, How to use that one? with robot_localization.

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-01-22**:
Thanx @tom moore I can see in rviz. Understood my mistake.

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-01-22**:
@Tom Moore
But Can you tell me, How should I decide values for Covariance matrix.
I dropped one mail to you. Waiting for reply.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-01-22**:
Yes, I'm afraid I've been a bit busy the past couple weeks. I'll look into it as soon as possible.